# Represent interval between values in ggplot2 geom_line()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot a large amount of data, but most of them are equal to 0. My idea was, in order to save space and computation time, to not store values equal to 0.

Furthermore, I want to use `geom_line()` function of `ggplot2` package in R, because with my data, this representation is the best one and has the aesthetics that I want.

My problem is: How, between two values of my X axis, can I plot a line at 0. Do I have to generate the associated Data Frame or a trick is possible to plot this?

Example:

```
    X    Y
   117   1
   158  14
   179   4
   187   1
   190   1
   194   2
   197   1
   200   4
   203   3
   208   1
   211   1
   212   5
   218   1
   992   15
  1001   1
  1035   1
  1037   28
  1046   1
  1048   1
  1064   14
  1078   1

# To generate the DF
X <- c(117, 158, 179, 187, 190, 194, 197, 200, 203, 208, 211, 212, 218, 992, 1001, 1035, 1037, 1046, 1048, 1064, 1078)
Y <- c(1,14,4,1,1,2,1,4,3,1,1,5,1,15,1,1,28,1,1,14,1)
data <- data.frame(X,Y)
g <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = data$X, y = data$Y))
g <- g + geom_line()
g
```

To give you an idea, that I am trying to do is to convert this image:

to something like this: 
http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=407269stack2.png

To generate the second figure, I have to define two positions around peaks in order to have this good shape.

I tried to change the scale to continuous scale, or discrete, but I did not have good peaks. So, there is a trick to say at `ggplot2`, if a position in X axis is between two values of X, this position will be display at 0?

Thank you a lot, any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that R doesn't see any interval values of X.  You can fix that by doing the following:

```
X <- c(117, 158, 179, 187, 190, 194, 197, 200, 203, 208, 211, 212, 218, 992, 1001, 1035, 1037, 1046, 1048, 1064, 1078)
Y <- c(1,14,4,1,1,2,1,4,3,1,1,5,1,15,1,1,28,1,1,14,1)
```

Which is your original data frame.

```
Z <- data.frame(seq(min(X),max(X)))
```

Creates a data frame that has all of the X values.

```
colnames(Z)[1] <- "X"
```

Renames the first column as "X" to be able to merge it with your "data" dataframe.

```
data <- data.frame(X,Y)
data <- merge(Z[1],data, all.x = X)
```

Creates a new data frame with all of the interval X values.

```
data[is.na(data)] <- 0
```

Sets all X values that are NA to 0.

```
g <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = data$X, y = data$Y))
g <- g + geom_line()
g
```

Now plots it.

Comment: This is a very nice way to do it! Thank you a lot, I did not have this kind of operations in mind... Thanks!